# Deprecated API Usage - Apple no longer accepts submissions of apps that use QuickTime APIs

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, app-store, qtkit

Application use Qtkit framework.

When try to upload to iTunes,  error message appear: invalid binary.

I received mail with : Deprecated API Usage - Apple no longer accepts submissions of apps that use QuickTime APIs.

source : https://developer.apple.com/quicktime/
QTKit

QTKit is a Cocoa framework for manipulating time-based media  providing a set of easy to use classes and methods to handle capture,  playback, editing, and export. Use these resources for integrating media  into your app.

QuickTime

QuickTime provides a powerful C based API for manipulating  time-based media, allowing low-level media export, editing, encoding and  decoding. While QTKit is the preferred API for use with time-based  media, a good understanding of QuickTime is essential for all  developers.

As result: QuickTime and Qtkit are different API's.

Please confirm what Apple no longer accepts submissions of apps that use QuickTime API and QTKit

Comment: Sorry, what’s the question?

Comment: For me is not clear QTKIK is not the same framework as QuickTime.  Deprecated API Usage - Apple no longer accepts submissions of apps that use QuickTime APIs - this response is generic.                                                           To to upload app to store i need to rewrite app using AVFOUNDATION ?

Comment: QuickTime has been ported over to AVFoundation, in 10.8 I believe.

Answer (score 3):

It certainly appears so. QTKit isn’t the same as QuickTime but it’s on top of it, and QuickTime isn’t moving into the future very gracefully. Apple doesn’t want to have to keep piling hacks on top of hacks to keep QuickTime working on newer machines and operating systems.

The good news is AVFoundation is kind of awesome.

Comment: From what I heard AVFoundation doesn't allow to install 3rd party decoders, so no mkv support anymore with that :-(

Comment: Yeah, the lack of plugin support sucks, but maybe they'll add it in the future?